# How to print HTML code in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to develop a simple PHP page that allow me to print some data in a database. The problem is that some data aren't "clean", i think that in the data there are some html tag (i suppose).

An example of data is the following:

```
%3Ch1%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%22color%3A+rgb%280%2C+0%2C+51%29%3B%22%3EDirettore+Artistico%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fh1%3E
```

To solve my problem i tried this:

```
<?php
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT text FROM mutable WHERE (id_obj = 1)");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
 echo "<p>" . html_entity_decode($row['text']) . "</p>";  
}
```

This solution don't work, i don't know if is important but the charset of my db is : latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: How are you receiving this data? It looks urlencoded.

Comment: This data are store in a database, i have no idea about how is store. 
I must parse this data and recover the text without any tag.

These data have been created with a kind of editor type that used by cms

Comment: Please stop using the `mysql` extension for php - it's [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its urlencoded html

[Check this](http://php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php): `urlencode($userinput)` outputs:

```
%3Ch1%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%22color%3A+rgb%280%2C+0%2C+51%29%3B%22%3EDirettore+Artistico%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fh1%3E
```

[And this](http://php.net/manual/de/function.urldecode.php): `urldecode($userinput)` outputs:

```
<h1><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 51);">Direttore Artistico</span></h1>
```

**EDIT:**

From your question:

```
<?php
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT text FROM mutable WHERE (id_obj = 1)");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
 echo "<p>" . html_entity_decode($row['text']) . "</p>";  
}
```

**DO NOT** use mysql_* functions. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php) instead.

**[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)**

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know how this data is produced it's impossible to know what transformations to do to get the original. It *looks* like the data is `urlencoded`, that's easy enough to reverse with `urldecode`.

If you want the HTML to be interpretted you can do:

```
echo '<p>' . urldecode($row["text"]) . '</p>';
// result:
<p><h1><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 51);">Direttore Artistico</span></h1></p>
```

If you want the HTML to show as it's plaintext you need to encode it:

```
echo '<p>' . htmlspecialchars(htmlenturldecode($row["text"])) . '</p>';
// result:
<p>&lt;h1&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: rgb(0, 0, 51);&quot;&gt;Direttore Artistico&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/h1&gt;</p>
```

Answer (score -2):

**strong text**

```
$string= "%3Ch1%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%22color%3A+rgb%280%2C+0%2C+51%29%3B%22%3EDirettore+Artistico%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fh1%3E";
echo urldecode($string);
```

?>